# getViewById() in ListView NullPointerException

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a View in a custom layout of a ListView, now I want to assign an onClickListener to this View (in a Fragment). But if I try

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rowleft).setOnClickListener( ...
```

it throws a NullPointerException. Why is this? In the layout file the View has the ID "rowleft" Does the id change when it is in a ListView? Or how do I see which row triggered the event?
What I want is two Views in one Item to know if the user clicked on the left or the right side.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean your view is the row of list view? In this case you will need to set onItemClickListener on the listView not in your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your `OnClickListener`s in your adapter `getView()` where you're setting up the listview item view anyway.

You can override `getView()` in an `ArrayAdapter`. Call `super.getView()` to get the view to call `findViewById()` on for the purpose of setting click listeners.

Don't call `findViewById()` on the activity. Even when the listview items are part of the activity hierarchy, it's not really practical to find views with the same id from different listview items.

Comment: The ListView is set up by this code: 
"String[] listitems = {"A","b","C","d","E","f"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.drinkrow,R.id.name,listitems); setListAdapter(adapter);"
In a ListFragment class in the onActivityCreated Method

Comment: You can override an `ArrayAdapter`'s `getView()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

ListView.getChildAt(x).findViewById(R.id.rowleft).setOnClickListener( ...

Comment: you'd have to provide more code and explain your view organization better